# How to define $\mathbb{R}$ in ZF(C) minus power set axiom

Tags: set-theory

Can $\mathbb{R}$ be defined in ZF(C) set theory minus power set axiom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. (Or rather, you can *define it* just fine; you just can't prove it exists).

Working in full ZFC, the set of all hereditarily countable sets will be a model of ZFC$-$Power Set, but does not contain any set that is large enough to be $\mathbb R$.

(By "large enough to be $\mathbb R$" I mean a set which *at the metalevel* is in bijective correspondence with the model's class of subsets of $\mathbb N$. Certainly a set that the model thinks is $\mathbb R$ would be in such a correspondence *within the model* and therefore also at the metalevel. But the hereditarily countable sets don't even contain something that has such a correspondence at the metalevel).

Comment: While your answer is correct, it is a bit misleading: There are transitive, countable models of $\operatorname{ZFC}^{-} + \mathbb R \text{ exists}$. Those don't contain sets large enough to be $\mathbb R$, but still they think that some of their small sets should be $\mathbb R$. The reason $H_{\omega_1}$ believes that there is not set that contains all the reals is a little more subtle - $H_{\omega_1}$ does contain all the reals of $V$, it can correctly determine whether a set is a real or not, so the only candidate to be the set of its reals is the real $\mathbb R$ which it doesn't contain.

Comment: @Stefan: By "large enough to be $\mathbb R$" in this context I meant "large enough (seen from the metalevel) to have an element for every subset of $\mathbb N$ the model knows". In this sense the $\mathbb R$ in your countable model _is_ large enough to serve as an $\mathbb R$ in the model.

Comment: Okay, so $\mathcal M$ has an element 'large enough to be $\mathbb R$' iff '$\mathcal M \models \mathbb R \text{ exists}$' - fine. At that point your answer should clarify this statement and ideally include a justification (outline of a proof) of this fact.

Comment: @Stefan: No, not exactly -- consider for example a countable model of ZFC minus Power Set plus "$\mathbb N$ has no power set". That does not contain an $\mathbb R$, but it does contain a set that is _large enough_ to have been $\mathbb R$ (because all that's needed to be large enough is to be countably infinite seen from the metalevel, because the model knows only countably infinite many subsets of $\mathbb N$, again counted at the metalevel).

Comment: I know what you're trying to say and I have absolutely no issues with that, but I don't think that you express your thoughts very clearly in this particular answer and I'd like it to be clarified such that students, who don't necessarily know what you have in mind, don't jump to false conclusions.