# What ZF axioms does Cantor's diagonal argument require?

Tags: set-theory

What ZF axioms does Cantor's diagonal argument require? Cantor's diagonal argument is often presented without reference to any of ZF axioms, so comes my question.

For this question, I will limit to the scope to uncountability of the set of real numbers.

Comment: Are you asking about uncountability of the real numbers?  A "diagonal argument" could be more general, as when Cantor showed a set and its power set cannot have the same cardinality, and has found many applications.

Comment: Yes, I am asking less general version of diagonal argument - the one involving uncountability of the real numbers

Comment: I know that, without the power set axiom, it's impossible to prove that uncountable sets exist. But that's not because you can't prove $\Bbb R$ is uncountable; it's because you can't prove $\Bbb R$ exists in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.  For the benefit of Readers, note the [related Question by OP](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046774/how-to-define-mathbbr-in-zfc-minus-power-set-axiom) that concerns what axioms are necessary to construct the real numbers.

Comment: I'm confused by the downvote; this seems a reasonable question.

Comment: Can't help with the reals (beyond my abilities), but, for what it's worth, I can formally prove that the power set of natural numbers is uncountable. The only set-theoretic axioms I required were the equivalents of the power set and separation axioms in ZFC. http://www.dcproof.com/Countable.htm There, I state the Peano Axioms for completeness at the beginning, but use only the fact that N is a set.

Answer (score 8):

The main axiom involved is **Separation**: given a formula $\varphi$ with parameters and a set $x$, the collection of $y\in x$ satisfying $\varphi$ is a set. (The set $x$ here is crucial - if we wanted the collection of all $y$ such that $\varphi(y)$ holds to be a set, this would lead to a contradiction via Russell's paradox.)

The way this is applied is as follows: suppose $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. We apply Separation to $\mathbb{N}$: let $\varphi(x)$ be the formula "$x\not\in f(x)$". (Note that this uses $f$ as a parameter.) Applied to $\mathbb{N}$, this gives a set $A$ which cannot be in the range of $f$, since $A=f(n)$ implies $n\in A\iff n\not\in f(n)\iff n\not\in A$.

Incidentally, this does *not* require that $\mathbb{R}$ exist as a set. $\mathbb{R}$ is a *definable class* even if it is not a set, and we can phrase Cantor's theorem as "For any function with domain $\mathbb{N}$, there is a real not in the range of the function". So Powerset plays no role here. Neither does Replacement, since we don't need the range of $f$ to be a set. Pairing is also irrelevant - although dropping pairing means we might not have functions at all, that just makes Cantor's result vacuously true. Union and Foundation didn't show up at all, and - perhaps surprisingly - we never used Extensionality either: we merely needed the *converse*, that two equal sets have the same elements, and this is a consequence of the laws of first-order logic alone.

If, however, you want the theorem to exist *in the right context*, then Powerset, Pairing, and Extensionality should all be assumed - Extensionality so that sets mean what they should, and Powerset and Pairing so that $\mathbb{R}$ and some functions exist in the first place.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote?

Comment: I would add that none of this is particular to $\mathbb{N}$: Separation is all you need to prove "If $X$ is a set, then for any function on $X$ there is some subset of $X$ not in its image".  To apply this to any particular set, though, you might need additional axioms to know that the set in question exists to begin with (for instance, Infinity for $X=\mathbb{N}$).  And if you want this to apply to actual real numbers rather than subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, you may need some other axioms depending on precisely how you choose to define real numbers in set theory.

Comment: @EricWofsey Indeed. And for the OP, there *are* set theories without separation, where sets *can* surject onto their powersets; e.g. Quine's theory $NF$. However, those set theories are really more of a curiosity for the most part; separation is a really nice axiom to have.

Comment: Well, NF does have separation because it has full blown comprehension. But it's just limited to stratified formulae.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I wouldn't call that separation, or full-blown comprehension, then. :) But the point is well taken.