# Why must Cantor's diagonal argument necessarily imply $|P(\mathbb{N})|>|\mathbb{N}|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

NEW EDIT

I realize now from the answers and comments directed towards this post that there was a general misunderstanding and poor explanation on my part regarding what part of Cantor's proof I actually dispute/question. As I see it, the proof follows 5 steps:

1. Given any set $S$, consider an *arbitrary* function $f:S \rightarrow P(S)$
2. Given $f$ define the set $D:=\{x|x\notin f(x)\}$
3. Prove that $D$ cannot be in the range of $f$
4. Since there exists a $D \in P(S)$ not in the range of $f$, $f$ cannot be a bijection
5. Since $f$ was chosen arbirarily, there does not exist a bijection from $S$ to $P(S)$

It seems that most (if not all) of the answers and comments assume that I have difficulty appreciating the necessity of step 1 or the chain of implications from step 3 to 5. Really, all I ever wondered about was how we can establish the validity of step 2.

While, it may be unreasonable to insist that "Only sets which we can prove exist, exist" especially since it's a very vague statement, in this case, the whole proof hinges on $D$ actually being a set, and I don't know of any other way of how to establish that except through using the axioms. And yes, while this just seems to be a simple application of the Axiom Schema of Separation (as Noah points out in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2046865/164699/) to a post regarding what axioms are needed to prove Cantor's diagonal argument), I feel there is a difficulty in that $f$ must be arbitrary. If there is truly nothing wrong in defining $D$ then there should be no problem with the following:

> For a given nonempty set $T$, arbitrary function $g:T \rightarrow P(T)$ and an arbitrary fixed element $t \in T$, define $E:=\{ x \; | \; t \in g(x) \}$

In this case, since $g$ is arbitrary, $E$ could be *any* subset of $T$, thus implying that every subset of a set is a set, totally obviating the need for the Axiom Schema of Separation at all.

So if we want to take the Axiom Schema of Separation as necessary, then I don't see how we can refer to an arbitrary function $f:S \rightarrow P(S)$ in Cantor's proof and establish the existence of $D$ without encountering logical difficulties.

---

---

I'm wondering why we conclude from Cantor's diagonal argument that $P(\mathbb{N})$ has a strictly greater cardinality than $\mathbb{N}$ when we don't reach such a conclusion in other contexts. For example, let $T_n$ represents $n^{th}$ primitive recursive function under some suitable enumeration. Then the computable function $f(n)=T_n(n)+1$ cannot be primitive recursive through the diagonal argument, but we don't (and shouldn't) conclude that set of computable functions must be uncountable. Rather we recognize that there are computable functions which are not primitive recursive.

For sets, I feel the issue is a little more subtle and I'm wondering if instead of concluding from Cantor's diagonal argument that $P(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable, we should really conclude that we should question whether $P(\mathbb{N})$ should be allowed to be considered a set. It seems at least to me (although I don't have a formal proof) that allowing $P(\mathbb{N})$ as a set establishes the inconsistency of ZF: If $P(\mathbb{N})$ exists then all of its elements should be sets. But since there are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and only countably many derivations/descriptions of sets built up from the axioms of ZF (or any other axiomatic system) then this means that uncountably many elements of $P(\mathbb{N})$ cannot be sets in ZF.

Looking at it another way, since $P(\mathbb{N})$ contains every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ as a set, that means that in particular $True(ZF)$, the set of Godel numbers of all true statements in ZF, should be one of its elements and therefore a set in ZF. Being a set in ZF it should also have a finite construction from the axioms of ZF. But we know from Tarski's theorem that as long as ZF is consistent $True(ZF)$ cannot be definable.

Am I missing something here? Has any set theorist of logician ever brought up this issue?

---

**EDIT**

I realize now that there were serious issues with what I claimed in the second and third paragraphs of my question, namely that the existence of a power set implies that ZF is inconsistent. I realize that I shouldn't have made those assertions due to my limited knowledge of model theory.

However, I think the issue raised in my first paragraph (and implied by the title of my question) still stands, that is what we can truly conclude from Cantor's diagonal argument. I understand now (from the comments and answers provided already) that the axioms of ZF describe the universe of sets but don't define all of the sets. However, we can define some sets through a chain of applications of the axioms, much like a formal proof of a theorem can be constructed from a series of formulas connected through rules of inference. I take for example establishing an individual von Neumann integer given the existence of the empty set and pairing.

Now in order for Cantor's diagonal argument to carry any weight, we must establish that the set it creates actually exists. However, I'm not convinced we can always to this: For if my sense of set derivations is correct, we can assign them Godel numbers just as with formal proofs. Then, we can define an injective function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow P(\mathbb{N})$ as $$f(n) = \text{the set} \; S_n \; \text{definable by the set derivation with Godel number} \; n $$

Using the axiom of separation we can define Cantor's diagonal set $A=\{ n | n \notin f(n) \}$ and conclude as usual that $A$ is not in the range of $f$. However, since we can "derive" $A$ (in the sense above) using $f$ and the axiom of separation, it has a Godel number and should be in the range of $f$. Therefore, it seems to me that we should conclude from this apparant contradiction something other than $|P(\mathbb{N})|>|\mathbb{N}|$. Maybe, we can't properly define $f$ and $A$ is not a set, or there is an issue with the axiom of separation or power set.

Comment: "Being a set in ZF it should also have a finite construction from the axioms of ZF. " **Citation needed**. The ZF axioms don't *build* the set-theoretic universe, they *describe* it: there's no assertion like "only the sets we can prove exist, exist" (whatever that would mean - there are important subtleties to phrasing that sort of statement precisely). That's not the only issue here, but it's the biggest one. (And in this context, the answer to "Am I missing something here? Has any set theorist of logician ever brought up this issue?" is *always* "yes and yes.")

Comment: There’s a lot to comment on here, but one error you’re making is assuming every set must have a “derivation/description built up from the axioms.”

Comment: @Noah So $True(ZF)$ is a valid set?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "true statement in ZF".  There is a set of statements which are true in every model of ZF, and that is a perfectly good set (it's the set of statements that are provable from ZF).

Comment: How would your proposed argument "totally obviate the need for the Axiom Schema of Separation"?  The argument itself _uses_ Separation, to conclude that $E$ is a set...

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm sorry for not being clear. What I meant was there is no need for a parameter in the Axiom if any possible subset is allowed to be a set. I don't know how such a "different axiom" would be formulated, but the fact that the Axiom of Separation was structured the way it was (that is to avoid Russell's paradox, etc.) abandoning the parameter seems like it would allow for other paradoxes/inconsistencies to creep in.

Comment: Your argument does use Separation with a parameter though (namely $g$).  Cantor's diagonal argument also uses Separation with a parameter (namely $f$).  I don't know where you are getting the idea of "abandoning the parameter" from.

Comment: You're right about my argument using a parameter. What I meant was if we accept the use of Axiom of Separation using an arbitrary parameter like $f$ then we should accept the use of $g$ in my argument. But, my argument implies that then any collection of elements of a set would be deemed a set itself and so the need for a parameter in the standard definition of the Axiom of separation turns out to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Ari But, again, your argument that you claim renders separation with a parameter unnecessary **uses** separation with a parameter. So how was it unnecessary? Let me take a stab at what I *think* you're trying to get at here: "Since I can use an *arbitrary* parameters in separation, this means that I can, by making various choices of parameters, prove an *arbitrary* subset of a set is a set. So why do we need to do the whole song and dance with formulae. Wouldn't a simpler axiom just be to say a subset of a set is a set?" Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am saying (although I'd probably skip the song and dance)

Comment: @Ari Could keep going here, but I think you should formulate this carefully and ask another question, since the comments here have become long and the question has moved a long way from the original question that the answers and earlier comments address.

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues here.

First, you are conflating *theories* (like ZF) and *models*. What is true is that:

- For any model $M$ of ZF, there is a real - possibly not in $M$ - coding the theory of $M$.
- Whenever this real *is* in $M$, it can't be a *definable element* of $M$. But note that in general a theory may have multiple models which disagree over whether a certain sentence is true - this happens [precisely when](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) the theory is incomplete, which ZF is (assuming it's consistent of course). In particular, we can have a situation where one model $M$ "sees" another model $N$, and hence can define truth for it, but this doesn't contradict Tarski since the theory of $M$ will be different (necessarily!) from the theory of $N$.
- There is a set $Prove(ZF)$ of sentences true *in every model of* ZF. But - since ZF is incomplete, as noted above - this will never cover the set of *all* true sentences in any model. For a concrete example, it will contain neither the continuum hypothesis nor the negation of the continuum hypothesis. We can have $Prove(ZF)$ be a definable element of a model $M$ of ZF without contradicting Tarski, since $Prove(ZF)\not=Th(M)$.

However, this is a secondary issue. The real issue is that you seem to implicitly be assuming something along the lines of "Only sets which *must* exist *do* exist." That is, that in some sense the ZF axioms "build" the universe of sets, and consequently that every set is "definable" in an appropriate sense. This is not the case. The ZF axioms *describe* the universe of sets, but at no point do we posit that the only sets which exist are those which can be "constructed via the ZF axioms" in some way; and indeed it's not clear how to even phrase that precisely.

(There are also issues about *internal* versus *external* properties like [Skolem's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%27s_paradox), and the subtleties around undefinability exemplified by the existence of [pointwise-definable models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597), but those are more advanced topics and should only be treated after the basics are understood.)

---

EDIT:

However, I think the real interesting point here is the question you raise:

> What's the right connection to see between using diagonalization to prove *uncountability* versus using diagonalization to prove *the existence of a non-p.r. function*?

The point is:

> Given any "reasonable class" $\mathcal{C}$ of functions, there is no binary function in $\mathcal{C}$ which lists all unary functions in $\mathcal{C}$: that is, there is no binary $f\in\mathcal{C}$ such that for every unary $g\in \mathcal{C}$ we have $\forall x [f(n)(x)=g(x)]$ for some $n$.

For example, taking $\mathcal{C}$ to be the class of all functions gives Cantor's theorem as usual, with slightly tweaked language: we think of a list of unary functions $(h_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ as a single binary function $f(i,x)=h_i(x)$. So "$\forall x [f(n)(x)=g(x)]$" is just a fancy way to say "$g$ is the $n$th function on the list (represented by) $f$."

You can think of this as saying:

> No "reasonable" class of functions can tell that it is countable (even if it is), in the sense that no "reasonable" class of functions contains a single (binary) function listing all of its (unary) functions.

For example, the set of primitive recursive functions isn't "primitively recursively countable" in the sense that there is no primitive recursive listing of the primitive recursive functions. But this doesn't let us conclude that the set of primitive recursive functions is *genuinely uncountable*. (It doesn't let us conclude that it's countable, either; we have to do additional work to tell whether the set of primitive recursive functions is countable.)

Now the point is that when we look at the class of *all* functions, we're not missing any potential information: if there were a way to count the class of all functions, we'd see it in the class of all functions. So that's why "the set of primitive recursive functions isn't primitive recursively countable" and "the set of functions isn't countable" are true for the same reason.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84612/discussion-on-answer-by-noah-schweber-why-must-cantors-diagonal-argument-necess).

Answer (score 1):

In Cantor's diagonal proof it is shown that if $S$ is a countable subset of the set $T$ of all subsets of $\Bbb N$ then there is a member of $T$ that is not in $S.$

In the diagonal proof that there are functions that are not primitive recursive it is shown that if $S^*$ is the set of primitive  recursive functions then there is a function $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ that is not in $S^*$.

That is not paradoxical. It would be, if we were to claim that the set $T^*$ of all $g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ was equal to $S^*$.

Comment: I'm not claiming that there is any paradox but rather that the diagonal argument applied to primitive recursive functions does not establish that $T^*$ is uncountable but only that, as you stated, there exists a function $f \in T^*$  not in $S^*$ (I was also pointing out that the set ot all computable functions is still countable even though any diagonal argument on the primitive recursive functions creates a computable function). Thus, my issue with Cantor's diagonal argument centers around what it really establishes: whether we should infer $|P(\mathbb{N}|>|\mathbb{N}|$ or something else.

Comment: @Ari The key thing in the Cantor argument is that it establishes that an *arbitrary* enumeration of subsets of $\mathbb N$ is not surjective onto $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. I think you are assuming connections between these two diagonalization proofs that, if you look closer, aren't there. They are different arguments, despite the fact that they both use diagonalization. (Does the enumeration of PR functions in that proof need to be artbitrary? Do we know it is an enumeration of *all* of them? Are we trying to show it isn't? Etc.)

Comment: @Ari Or maybe, per Noah's update, you *can* put them into the exact same form of argument, but it requires making the appropriate analogy for 'countable'. I think it's more straightforward to see the differences in the typical phrasings of the arguments, but either way, a better understanding shows there's no contradiction.